# nl2br() creates an extra new line

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert a description text field into the database.

I was previously just doing something like this:

```
$group_description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['group_description']);
```

But it was creating problems because when I was taking things out of the database, they were being displayed with \n\r strings instead of new lines.

Here is an example of a page with that problem:

http://www.comehike.com/hikes/hiking_group.php?hiking_group_id=48

So I tried to fix it by adding nl2br like this:

```
$group_description = mysql_real_escape_string(nl2br($_POST['group_description']));
```

But that just inserted an extra line :( Here is the example of the current problem:

http://www.comehike.com/hikes/hiking_group.php?hiking_group_id=50

Here is an example of an insert statement I use:

```
$insert_group_sql =  'INSERT INTO hiking_groups( title , group_description ) VALUES ( "'.$group_name.'" , "'.$group_description.'" ) ';
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Here is the code I use to display the $group_description

```
          //Convert all urls to links
          $group_description = preg_replace('#([\s|^])(www)#i', '$1http://$2', $group_description);
          $pattern = '#((http|https|ftp|telnet|news|gopher|file|wais):\/\/[^\s]+)#i';
          $replacement = '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>';
          $group_description = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $group_description);

          $group_description = str_replace("\'" , "'", $group_description );
          $group_description = nl2br($group_description);

          /* Convert all E-mail matches to appropriate HTML links */
          $pattern = '#([0-9a-z]([-_.]?[0-9a-z])*@[0-9a-z]([-.]?[0-9a-z])*\\.';
          $pattern .= '[a-wyz][a-z](fo|g|l|m|mes|o|op|pa|ro|seum|t|u|v|z)?)#i';
          $replacement = '<a href="mailto:\\1">\\1</a>';
          $group_description = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $group_description);
```

Comment: It's better practice to store them as newlines in the DB, and only convert to `<br>` tags when you actually come to output them to the browser.

Comment: Do you escape the output from your DB somehow in the browser? I think that this might be the reason for seing \n\r. Does the data look ok in DB? For example when you look it through phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @Yasen I posted the code that I use to display the group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I suggest that you do as Spudley suggests, keep it in the original form in the database and format it once you display it.

`nl2br()` should work, so I suggest that you check the input data to see exactly what is being input (which is easier to do if you don't format it before you store it in the DB). What it do is it takes \n, \n\r, \r\n and \r and inserts a `<br/>` instead. You should check that for instance there is no space in between \n and \r.

Also, make sure that you only use `nl2br()` in one place, since it doesn't replace the new lines, it just inserts the `<br/>` (that is, if you do `nl2br(nl2br($group_description))` you will get two `<br/>`)

**Update:**

I see in the additional code that when you display the description, you already have a `nl2br()`. You need to remove one of them, so that you only add the `<br/>`s once.

Also, instead of this:

```
      $group_description = str_replace("\'" , "'", $group_description );
      $group_description = nl2br($group_description);
```

Try this:

```
      $group_description = stripslashes($group_description);
      $group_description = nl2br($group_description);
```

That should remove all the sanitizing that `mysql_real_escape_string()` did, which should solve the problem of the \n\r showing in the text.

Comment: sorry, not quite following. I have to format before things get into the db, at least with the mysql_real_escape_string call.

Comment: Yes, but not with the nl2br(). mysql_real_escape_string() sanitizes the string, not formatting it. Display formatting should only be done when displaying. (say for instance that you in the future wants people to fetch the group descriptions through xml, json or anything else, then a `<br/>` might not really show up well, so there are other benefits from it as well)

Comment: but then how do I fix the problem I had here: http://www.comehike.com/hikes/hiking_group.php?hiking_group_id=48 where there was an \r\n appearing on the page even though I used the nl2br() before displaying it?

Comment: Updated the answer, the `mysql_real_escape_string()` also escapes the new lines, which means that they are not actually \n\r, they are \\n\\r (which also explains why you got 4 new lines in the display). The final result on the second page actually looks like `<br/>\\n\\r` after the insert to the database and `<br/>\<br/>\n\<br/>\r` when displaying after the second `nl2br()` have been run.

Comment: ok, that was not really correct either and I can't count. I see in the code that there is 4, but that only explains 3 of them. The only way I can see it is that you have the `magic_quotes_gpc` directive set to true (which automatically escapes all of them, which really messes up the data). If that is the case, you will have to do `$group_description = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['group_description']));` as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try trim before passing to nl2br:

```
nl2br( trim($_POST['group_description']) )
```

Comment: @Eriks that does not help because there are many new lines in between the text.  Not just in the beginning and end.

Comment: What if to remove duplicated <br>?
like preg_replace("/(<br>)+/", "", $message)